# How to group docs by latest and run aggregation on the group in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I need to get all clients under a partnerId & since there would be many duplicate clients I need to group the clients by clientId,reportDate and run some aggregations on it.

Index data is like below -

```
[
    {  partnerId: "PID1234", clientId: "c1234", reportDate: "2022-02-01"   }, // dup
    {  partnerId: "PID1234", clientId: "c1234", reportDate: "2030-02-01"   }, // dup, agg should take this one only since this is the latest.
    {  partnerId: "PID1111", clientId: "c1222", reportDate: "2010-02-01"   },
    {  partnerId: "PID2222", clientId: "c1444", reportDate: "2013-02-01"   },
 ]
```

I need to do something like the below query, the problem is top hits don't accept sub aggregations -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "partnerId": "PID1234"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "groupp": {
      "top_hits": {
        "sort": [
          {
            "clientId": {
              "order": "desc"
            }
          }
        ],
        "size": 1,
        "aggs": {
            "total_engagement_count": {
              "sum": { "field": "recommendations.totalEngagement" }
            }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using top_hits aggregation? You can group by client id and reportDate using terms aggregation, which accepts sub aggregations. If you still want to group documents, you can check [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) and see if it works for you. Keep in my that field collapsing does not effect aggregations. It is just for grouping documents.

Comment: @YD9 I'm using top_hits to do the grouping. after I group it I need to run the aggs on the grouped result.
I tried field collapsing but aggregations won't run on the collapsed results as you said, so that's a problem.
Let me try terms aggregation as you said.I'm very new to elastic :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to change your approach.
Look at the answer below, aggs metrics don't allow sub aggs.

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16537#issuecomment-181965367

Comment: What should I use instead of the above query?. Can you help, I'm very new to elastic.
Need to group and run aggs on the group.